# How to get the text shown in Firefox dialog box

Tags: firefox

all,

I'm writing a Firefox extension in order to detect phishing attempts. As a lot of phishing web sites show alert/prompt dialog box, I want to capture the text inside for detection. I searched google but still haven't figured out which service should I use for this purpose. Can someone help me with it?

Thanks,

Comment: I did some search in mxr and found all of the dialog operations like alert, prompt all invoked openwindow. I will try enumerating all the windows and fetch the text inside, if it is possible.